# Design Patterns Real examples

Tags: design-patterns

I am looking to do some changes to my existing component at work and am starting to see the advantages of using design patterns. The problem is I have some specific examples for which I am trying to use what I learned in design patterns and am having issues doing that.
Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a existing component that monitors the performance of say n different software packages each catering to a specific type.
i.e Existing component

- package A for type 1
- package B for type 2
- package C for type 3 and so on....

Each package does some performance monitorings and has its own data logs, records, etc.. Each package has only one type now.

In the future we may have a new feature coming up for

-including a analysis log . This will have the data log that is already existing and add some other data on top of that.
-Suporting multiple types for a package.
i.e package A for type1, type 2 (Bitype)
    package B for type 1,type 2, type 3 (tritype)

Looking at this , I was thinking adapter pattern could be of use here.
I could use the existing component as the adaptee . Then do the new functonality in the adapter class. My target will be the final component with the 2 functionalities added.
Since, I am dealing with existing code here , i think i should add a adapter class to adapt the new features. But I am having second thoughts because , adapter is for making one interface usable with another interface. Here I have existing interface, but I do not have a target interface already present. I will have to create both the adapter and the target too. So am confused if this definition fits my requirement or not.

Could someone who has some experience with design patterns make your suggestions here.
Thanks

sure . The software is for sportsmen. The existing system tracks the training details of these sportsmen. It has details like training log, what brands they prefer and personal details etc. There is a seperate package created for a type of sportsmen. sportsmen types are tennis player, golf player, swimmer etc.So a sportsmen can be in one type only , either tennis player or golf player and not both. In the future there will be a requirement to include more functionality 1. to include a performance log(i.e take the already existing logs and add performance log details on top of it). 2. there can be overlapping sportsmen interests i.e a single sportmen can be participating in more than one sport. a single sportsmen could be participating in tennis, gold and swimming. hope it is clear now.

Comment: I think we need a few more details of what class structure you have at present, and what the interactions between the instances of those classes are. It isn't clear to me what 'package A for type 1' actually means. Can you list the classes that your monitoring component knows about, and what methods it calls on them? Does the monitoring component know about the types, or just the packages? Does each type/package look the same to the monitoring component, or does it call different methods on each one?

Comment: sure.. I updated the post with more specific details.. Pls let me know your views.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an interface for each common group of information and then implement them for reach type of sportsmen that they can be applied for.

```
interface IRunner
{
    int AverageSpeed {get; }

}

interface IBallPlayer
{
    int ShootingSpeed {get; }
}

class TennisPlayer : IBallPlayer;
class FootballPlayer : IRunner, IBallPlayer;
```

If that's not what you are looking for you have to be more specific and give some code examples showing existing code and some code example showing what you want to do.

A picture (code) is worth more than thousand words.

Comment: I am more interested in using the available design patterns like from the Gang of 4 book. Your solution looks more like a general sol. not specific to a design pattern

Comment: Would anyone have any other views on this?

Comment: Then you need to be more specific and also show the problem through code.